# Reset NixOS container

Tags: nixos, container, nix

Nixos containers can be created declaring them in the `configuration.nix`. Is there way to 'reset' them, hence delete all data, and recreate the container?

Answer (score 1):

NixOS containers store their root filesystem in `/var/lib/containers/%i` (where `%i` is the name of the container).

Additionally the container units create `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-container/%i` and `/nix/var/nix/gcroots/per-container/%i`. Delete those if you want to have the derivations used by the container garbage-collected.

Of course any of the `bindMounts` that you might have specified could also contain state.